# Split out column that contains both str and ints

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a column that should only contain ints however, due to data errors, it currently contains both strings and ints. I need to apply a `np.where` statement that says the following `np.where(df['IO8'] >= 2002),"NEW","OLD")`

The statement fails with the error cannot use >= on strings. How would I get around this? Any help would be great. Let me know if any more detail is needed. I have also tried to use regex like the following:

```
df['split'] = pd.np.where(df['IO8'].str.contains("^\d{4}$", regex=True), "Number", "Error")
df['IO8'] = pd.np.where(df['split'].str.contains("Number"), df['IO8'].astype(int), df['IO8'].astype(str))
df['split1'] = pd.np.where(df['split'].str.contains("Number") & (df['IO8'] >= 2002),"NEW","OLD")
```

But still get an error on this.

Comment: Just to make sure @Jezrael answer's work, could you `print(df['IO8'].head())` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get years to new column with convert to floats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IO8':['2000','2009','20','dwd21']})

df['num'] = df['IO8'].str.extract("(^\d{4}$)").astype(float)
```

Then is possible use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for 3 states:

```
m1 = df['num'].notna()
m2 = df['num'] >= 2002
df['split1'] = pd.np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2],["NEW","OLD"], default='no match')
```

Or use double `np.where`:

```
df['split1'] = pd.np.where(m2, "NEW", pd.np.where(m1, "OLD", 'no match'))

print (df)
     IO8     num    split1
0   2000  2000.0       OLD
1   2009  2009.0       NEW
2     20     NaN  no match
3  dwd21     NaN  no match
```

Because if use only `np.where` output is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IO8':['2000','2009','20','dwd21']})

df['num'] = df['IO8'].str.extract("(^\d{4}$)").astype(float)

m1 = df['num'].notna()
m2 = df['num'] >= 2002
df['split1'] = pd.np.where(m1 & m2, "NEW","OLD")

print (df)
     IO8     num split1
0   2000  2000.0    OLD
1   2009  2009.0    NEW
2     20     NaN    OLD
3  dwd21     NaN    OLD
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thanks for this! All the values in `df['num']` are coming out as NaN therefore the np.where all come out as OLD, any suggestions? I know 2002 does exist in the data so we should be getting some NEW

Comment: Hello Mustie, please edit your answer to show what your data looks like, otherwise we're guessing with our best knowledge.

Comment: @MustieMustafa - I think reason is `"(^\d{4}$)"` - reegx means check if columns contains only 4digits and no another values, if want extract `2000` from `2000data` then use `df['num'] = df['IO8'].str.extract("(\d{4})").astype(float)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks jezrael, indeed the issue was spacing around the numbers. Needed to trim the column first! THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

@Author, you would like to see this too

```
b = df['IO8'].apply(lambda x: "New" if (x.isnumeric() and int(x) >= 2002) else "None" if not x.isnumeric() else "Old")
```